# Laravel Get Body request and avoid Query string params

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

How to get body request parameters without the query string parameters in POST method.

when I used `$request->all()` it always returns all parameters including the Query string.

I have my own reason that's why I did not use `$request->only([])` or `$request->except([])`. (cause I want to create a global function)

I want to get the body request parameters only... How to do that?

Comment: did you try `$request->post()` ?

Comment: It's working bro. 
can you drop that answer below? So I can upvote. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similarly to how there is access to the query string via `$request->query()` there is access to the Request payload via `$request->post()`. These methods are accessing `$request->query` and `$request->request` Parameter Bags.

Both methods `query()` and `post()` have method signatures that allow you to pass a key to retrieve and a default value as well: `$key = null, $default = null`

Comment: Thanks so much! why isn't this documented!?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to get body request parameters without the query string:

```
$request->except(array_values(array_flip($request->query())));
```

You could have simply done this with the `post()` method on the request object:

```
$request->post();
```